# Question about a high voltage setup/scenario

Tags: high-voltage, discharge, corona

I was wondering what would occur in the following setup.  Say you have an circuit basically like this:[image]
V1 is a source of high voltage (high enough for corona discharge to occur), and no current can flow through the source.  The resistor has a high enough resistance that most of the current from the source leaves as corona discharge through the open wires.  The capacitor is initially charged to the same voltage as V1, and no corona discharge or leakage can occur from the capacitor, so it can only discharge by arcing across the small air gap and then through R1.  What I was wondering is does/can the corona discharging electricity from V1 prevent the capacitor from discharging?

Comment: please be clear when asking questions .... you have three labels named `V1` ..... the labels should really be different as in `V1, V2, V3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corona will create a conductive (ionized) path between the two nodes labeled `V1`, and they will have the same voltage as long as the path exists.

If you turn off the high-voltage generator, both nodes will discharge through the resistor until the ionization disappears. After that, the left node will continue to discharge, but the capacitor will not.

Comment: So the voltage source would essentially contribute to the breakdown rather than block it?